# How to realize one() like Python's any() and all()

Tags: python

I like to use `any()` and `all()` in Python. But sometimes I need a `one()`.

I want to know if **only one** value or condition in a list is `True`.

Currently I do it with such a nested ugly `if`.

```
# In real world there could be more then just two elements
istrue = [True, False]
isfalse = [True, 'foobar']
isfalse2 = [False, False]

def one(values):
    if values[0] and values[1]:
        return False
    if not values[0] and not values[1]:
        return False
    return True

one(istrue)  # True
one(isfalse)  # False
one(isfalse2)  # False
```

I assume there is a more pythonic way, isn't it?

Comment: Have you already tried it with this approach?

```python
def one(values):
    return True in values
```

Comment: @Yanni2 Your suggestion is an implementation of `any()`

Comment: @Gameplay Please read the question again.

Comment: @Gameplay, it looks like they want only one truthy value, not one `True`

Comment: Ok, @ypnos, you're right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sum(map(bool, l)) == 1
```

This is probably the shortest expression. It turns every item in the list into a boolean, and sums them. A truthy value will count as `1`, a falsey value as `0`. Thus if the sum is exactly `1`, there was exactly one truthy item in it.

If you want the short-circuiting behaviour of `all`/`any`, which avoids iterating *all* items unnecessarily, then something like this:

```
def one(l):
    truthy = 0
    for i in l:
        truthy += bool(i)
        if truthy > 1:
            return False
    return truthy == 1
```

Comment: Considering you are assigning 0 to truthy and short circuit if it's more than 1 you can just return `True` after the loop, no addded value in comparing to 1 (unless I'm missing something). Anyway +1, best answer imo.

Comment: No, `truthy` might still be `0` after the loop.

Comment: Ah, right. Nevermind the above then.

Answer (score 5):

Convert all elements to boolean and then sum them up:

```
def one(values):
    return sum(bool(x) for x in values) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a more Pythonic way to implement a function that checks if exactly one element in an iterable is True. Here's a more concise implementation using Python's built-in sum() function:

```py
def one(iterable):
    """Return True if exactly one element in the iterable is true."""
    return sum(map(bool, iterable)) == 1
```